# MySQL error : Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.dynamicFormId, max(s.version) FROM seralityportletpreferences s
INNER JOIN dynamicForm d on d.dynamicFormId = s.dynamicFormId
WHERE s.seralitypreferences LIKE CONCAT('%',(SELECT DISTINCT blockId, version FROM formBlock WHERE groupId = 10609 AND blockContent like '%911%'),'%')
GROUP BY d.dynamicFormId
```

Please tell me where I did mistake. I am using select statement in like clause

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve in `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.dynamicFormId, max(s.version) FROM seralityportletpreferences s
INNER JOIN dynamicForm d on d.dynamicFormId = s.dynamicFormId
WHERE s.seralitypreferences LIKE CONCAT('%',IFNULL((SELECT DISTINCT convert(varchar(50), blockId), version FROM formBlock WHERE groupId = 10609 AND blockContent like '%911%'),''),'%')
GROUP BY d.dynamicFormId
```